# Avoiding local variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I often encounter problems in terms of design if it comes to this point:

```
var pages,
    book
;

Book.findOne( { title: "First Book" }, function(err, doc) {
  pages = doc.pages;

  console.log( pages );
} );

res.json(pages, 200);
```

`pages` is undefined, though I set it to `doc.pages`. If I move the `res.json(pages, 200)` into the callback of `findOne` this script works perfectly.

Am I following a wrong pattern/code design when it comes to JavaScript or is there a solution to keep the `res.json()` out of the callback, apart from making `pages` global?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing `Book.findOne` a callback to be executed when a match is found. Afterwards you're invoking `res.json`, and passing it `pages` as an argument. It's important to understand that the callback will not have been executed by this time. Are you able to move the response inside the callback function?

```
Book.findOne({title: 'First Book'}, function (err, doc) {
  res.json(doc.pages, 200)
})
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine.
I already assumed that this is the more common usage patten in Javascript to work via Callbacks since code is executed asynchroniosly and not strictly from one line to the other.

Comment: @daemonfire300 code is not executed asynchronously. Callbacks are called asynchronously.